# Why is the limit removed from these derivative definition forms?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm attempting to study linear approximations and L'Hospital's rule. However, both sections of my book begin by saying something to the effect that I *obviously* should know that:

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$$

This form isn't something I'm used to seeing so I checked previous sections of my book to see what I'd missed. The most relevant thing I found was the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

It's pretty easy to derive the first formula from the second *if you ignore the limit operator*. Why is that part of the derivative being ignored? How can it be ignored without introducing some sort of logical error? The way these sections were written make me feel like I missed something fundamental about alternative forms of the definition of the derivative and their use.

Comment: The identity $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ is generally *false* unless $f$ is in the form $bx+c$.
Graphically similar possible statements are: 1) the first-order approximation $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+o(\lvert x-a\rvert)$ as $x\to a$, which means exactly that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{\lvert x-a\rvert}=0$; 2) Lagrange's theorem about the existence of some $\xi_{x,a}\in(x,a)\cup (a,x)$ such that $f(x)=f(a)+f'(\xi_{x,a})(x-a)$, provided that $a\ne x$ and that $f$ is continuous in $[a,x]\cup [x,a]$ and differentiable on $(a,x)\cup (x,a)$.

Comment: Recall the point-slope form of a line:  $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1).$$  Since the derivative gives the slope, and $y_1$ is the value of the function at $x_1$, substituting $x_1=a$ and $y_1=f(a)$, we have what is given after moving $f(a)$ to the other side.

Comment: I believe I have some additional studying to do before I can understand Gae's full comment. My book attempts to explain L'Hospital's rule using *linear* approximations so I can simply substitute as Andrew suggests.

Comment: I still think it's weird that if you do substitute $m=f'(x_{1})$ and solve for $f'(x_{1})$ you don't actually get the true definition of the derivative... o.0... but I guess if $a$ is sufficiently close to $x$ you can still get a good approximation?

Comment: The correct statement is $f(x) =f(a) +f'(a) (x-a) +o((x-a)) $ where $o((x-a) ) $ represents any function $g(x) $ such that $g(x) /(x-a) \to 0$. But this formulation does not help to explain/prove L'Hospital's Rule. The correct and honest approach is via Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I wonder why textbooks try to present wrong and irrelevant ideas instead of giving correct proofs. Please please leave all sorts of hand waving when writing math textbooks. Change your textbook if you can. If there is no alternative book use Wikipedia.